# Getting a row of pistons to trigger

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have been trying to get an row of 7 pistons to fire when a block has been pushed in front of the middle one. Every technique I try is not firing them. This is a Cobblestone floor maker. Here is an above view of the layout:

> P = Piston
> B = Block (I am using stone)
> A = AIR SPACE
> W = Water
> L = Lava
> X = Trigger Space
>
> BBBBBBBBBBBBB
>
> BLBPPPPPPPBLB
>
> PAAAAAXAAAAAP
>
> BwBAAAAAAABwB
>
> BBBAAAAAAABBB

Answer (score 5):

If I am correct that this is your layout:

[image]

Then this solution should work:

[image]

Note that this is a sticky piston.